# C# Remove AD Computer Account Running on Windows Service

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-services, directoryservices, domaincontroller

I want to write a function in a windows service application to remove a given computer name from Active Directory.

The Windows service is running on a machine which is domain-joined to the DC. Currently I have logged in to this machine with domain admin account.

The Windows service is running under the security context of "NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM" and this should not be changed, as there shouldn't be any user interaction after installing the application, meaning that admin shouldn't enter their credentials in services.

When I run the application with my newly added code to delete the computer account, it doesn't work. However, when I change the logon info on the Windows Service and update that with domain admin credentials, it's able to successfully remove the computer account from AD.

Below is [a shortened version of] the function used to delete computer accounts.

Is there any way I can modify the code to be able to remove Computer Accounts using the same security context (NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM)?

```
private void DeleteComputerAccount(string CompName, DirectoryEntry DirEntry)
{
    try
    {
        //Delete computer account
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(DirEntry, "(name=" + CompName + ")");
        SearchResult res = search.FindOne();
        res.GetDirectoryEntry().DeleteTree();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Throw();
    }
}
```

Where `DeleteComputerAccount` is called:

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.contoso.com");

string compName = "MyWorkstation01";
DeleteComputerAccount(compName, dirEntry);
```

Answer (score 1):

When a service runs as local system, it will access the network (and thus AD) in the security context of the host's computer account. You can delegate the computer account (or better, a group which the computer is a member of) the ability to delete objects from AD. This link has accurate advice on how to complete that task - http://sigkillit.com/2013/06/12/delegate-adddelete-computer-objects-in-ad/

While not what you asked, a couple other things stand out to me:

1. You're not filtering your search very well. You might get something other than what you want back. I'd suggest a filter like this instead: `(&(objectClass=computer)(sAMAccountName=<PCName>$))`
2. Local system is a lot of access. Could you run this as network service instead?

Comment: I agree. To add my 2 cents: It is usual (at least ins some big AD enterprise environments) to use AD "technical accounts" for that, and not to use local system. It is easier (and more common) too if you want to access remote CIFS shares (yes, this works with local system too if you add the machine account to the ACL, but I don't like it). Using technical accounts for that (one user per product or server) you have better central control. But you need some way to control logon as service privileges.